# Is there a way to get Stripe Account ID if I know customer ID?

Tags: stripe-payments

I use Stripe API and I need to get Stripe Account ID if I know customer ID. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where are you getting the Customer id from? A webhook? If it's a webhook obtained via Connect you can get the account id on the Event. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks

Answer (score 0):

You can get it at the end of the OAUTH flow when the account is connected see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts something like:

```
{
"token_type": "bearer",
"stripe_publishable_key": PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
"scope": "read_write",
"livemode": false,
"stripe_user_id": USER_ID,  //this is stripe account id
"refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
"access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
}
```